# Как добавить еще одно условие в выборку?

Tags: laravel

Добрый день как добавить еще одно условие к выборке ?

```
$base = Base::find($request->base_id);
$contracts = $base->contracts->where('end_actually', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
```

Как мне еще к условию where добавить еще один and where status = 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$contracts = $base->contracts->where([
  ['end_actually', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateString()],
  ['status', 1]
]);
```

Подробнее [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
$contracts = $base->whereHas('contracts', function($query) {
    $query->where('end_actually', '>', Carbon::today()->toDateString());
    $query->where('status', 1);
})->get();
```